# Too few nodes error after running the simulation

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, ltspice, mosfet-driver, gate-driving

[image]

What does "too few nodes" mean in this circuit?  Any connection error? If it is some library error, please help with the solution.

Comment: I'd suspect U1 and/or your use of U1. Is U1 using an encrypted model? Is it appropriate and tested for LTspice? Etc...

Comment: @periblepsis How to know that?

Comment: I've only seen that error when someone was using an encrypted model or when they were mis-applying a model they didn't well-understand. Also, I'm pretty sure that if you delete U1 and clean up a few details (perhaps) the error will go away. If it doesn't go away after removing U1, then post up the netlist and I'll try it myself. But I think U1 and/or your use of it is the issue here.

Comment: @periblepsis is correct. You’re using the PSpice encrypted model. Texas Instruments also provides the unencrypted version so you need to download that instead and try again.

Comment: I got the other model which is not encrypted. Thankyou so much!